# JSON vs. XML vs. SQL vs. JS - semi-special characters competition

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, json, xml

From MS-SQL we generate JSON and XML to be used by a JS function on client side (both Browser and App in Cordoba)

the name of the "fields" in JSON and SQL have to follow some logic and often compound other fields, and the JS function use a split to divide and use them separately

so far, requirements are not changeable ...
so we though something so simpler as make the names like Something.Otherthing.EvenOther ...

well, here start the fight, with the symbol used to concatenate names:

```
. => destroy the outputted JSON as it make it multilevel
_ => can't be used as already in naming convention on 
/ => introduce escape \ and JSON/XML are a mess
\ => not possible in JSON
= => breakes the XML
^ => same, XML broken
@ => same again
$ % & and so on => not even elegant, and difficult to read data
```

so far, our best bet is :

```
· => so far the most elegant and working solution, but not so intuitive
```

can be this true ?
what do you think guys ?
any other better character/symbol, intuitive, that's not treated like a especial character, that is posible to treat easily in SQL and JS and do not break XML and JSON, and that asure us no need to change in the next three months ?

Comment: hard to make any sense out of what your specific problem is. Provide a [mcve] and a better description of what you are trying to do

Comment: I think the specific problem is "requirements are not changeable" :-)

Comment: you say this breaks XML, the other breaks JSON, etc... surely those characters can be properly escaped so they don't "break" your file format?

Comment: Let me explain better,

Comment: Let me explain better, I will try ...

We aim to generate XML and JSON directly from the SQL server to be used by the JS.

Sure I can escape the symbols, but as we are building our "standard" we try to use a symbol not needed to be escaped, could you imagine that the two-dots, the dot, and the backslash should be escaped in URLs ?
http':'/\/\www'.'IBelieveThatNot'.'com/\WTF

and to impruve readability, we aim for a character that adds no noise:
This.is.easier.to.read
This&Is&Not&Easy

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand you correctly? All you need is a nice looking delimiter character, which will not break XML?

You might try the pipe sign:

```
SELECT 'test|character' FOR XML PATH('x')
```

Leads to

```
<x>test|character</x>
```

Comment: Yes, that right, a nice-looking delimiter, that do not breaks the XML, neither the JSON, and it is Painless in JS,

problem with pipe:
Column name 'i|Customer|Country' contains an invalid XML identifier as required by FOR XML; '|'(0x007C) is the first character at fault.

Answer (score 0):

More of a JSON guy, but I've adopted dashes.   They link to my classes and keep the naming conventions a little more readable.

```
Select [Ugly-Field-Name]=25
      ,[Another-Ugly]  ='Some Name' 
 For  XML PATH('row')
```

Returns

```
<row>
  <Ugly-Field-Name>25</Ugly-Field-Name>
  <Another-Ugly>Some Name</Another-Ugly>
</row>
```

RAW is readable as demonstrated below (my EAV function)

```
Declare @xml xml = (Select [Ugly-Field-Name]=25,[Another-Ugly]  ='Some Name' for XML RAW)
Select * from [dbo].[udf-EAV](@XML)
```

Returns

```
Entity  Attribute       Value
25      Another-Ugly    Some Name
```

And Finally, my JSON generator returns (field names are always converter to lowercase)

```
{"status": {"successful":true,"timestamp":"2016-52-03 19:52:27 GMT","rows":1,"runtime_ms":0.15},"results": [{"ugly-field-name":25,"another-ugly":"Some Name"}]}
```

Comment: in js be cleaner using underscore to allow dot notation when working with response. Not sure about yours but my js IDE will auto suggest with dots but not using `['string-name']`

Comment: @charlietfl  Yes, but for example $.go.application["banner-logo"]  returns "App_Images/Logo_Micro.png", but with approach I can use macro substitution  aa="banner-logo";$.go.application[aa]

Comment: but what's the advantage...adds an extra step and easier to write dot as well as get code intelisence with it... can still fallback to `[]` approach also as needed

Comment: @charlietfl code reduction via reusable functions and common data patterns.   It works for me.

Comment: still rather have both options myself...adding special characters in js property names seems pointless when you have a choice

Comment: @charlietfl Judging by your profile (yes I peeked), you are probably right.  That said, you might be impressed on how data-driven my apps are, both front-end and back.   Also, by consistently using [], I never get surprise.  Furthermore, the vast majority of MY field name are like you would expect, but sometimes I need to consume data with field names like "Weighted Average Interest Rate" (in my world WAIR)

Comment: oh not doubting it...just a believer in KISS and simplest approach to writing/debugging and since end consumer is JS I lean towards that side for simplification

Comment: Yes, that right, a nice-looking delimiter, that do not breaks the XML, neither the JSON, and it is Painless in JS, --  problem with pipe: Column name 'i|Customer|Country' contains an invalid XML identifier as required by FOR XML; '|'(0x007C) is the first character at fault.